# Find line containing string with special characters (including '|' and '*') in fasta file using bash script

Tags: bash, awk, grep, fasta

I was trying to use `awk` to find a line containing a string with format `abcd|efg-hi*jk|lmno` in a file, let's say `f.txt`. The string will necessarily be stored in a variable, say `$id`. Searching the file for `$id` isn't working, even though the file contains the string - my guess is this is due to the special characters. I'm trying to find the line following the one containing `$id` (as it will contain the sequence I'm looking for).

Any idea how to go about this? The following is that I have so far, but it doesn't work I think because `$id` contains special characters:

`awk -F, 'BEGIN{line=-1;str=""} $1 ~ /$id/ {line=NR} {if (line > 0 && NR > line) {if (substr($0, 1,1)==">") exit; str=str$0}} END{print str}' f.fasta`

Comment: `$1 == id { ... }`?

Comment: that doesn't work. `id` contains special characters so it returns an empty string

Comment: That's why you use equality instead of regular expression matching.

Comment: Oh, and you don't show in your code where you set the id variable in awk.

Comment: I tried that already and its returning an empty string. I said "I was trying to use awk to find a line containing a string with format abcd|efg-hi*jk|lmno in a file, let's say f.txt. The string will necessarily be stored in a variable, say $id. Searching the file for $id isn't working, even though the file contains the string" in the question.

Comment: Where are you setting the variable in awk? An awk variable is distinct from a shell variable and needs to be explicitly passed... if you search there are q&as that show how to do it.

Comment: oh, I'm not setting it in `awk`. i'm setting the variable like, `id="abcd|efg-hi*jk|lmno"`. in my initial try I searched for it like, `$0==">'$id'" {...}` (line is supposed to start with a `>` for fasta format) which also yielded empty string. But when I try, `$1 ~ /'abcd'/` i get what i'm looking for. the issue is that i can't search like that because for this script i'll only be able to work with `$id` (and i need the entire string as it's a unique identifier)

Comment: should this work? `awk -v id='>"$id"' -F, 'BEGIN{line=-1;str=""} $1 == id/ {line=NR} {if (line > 0 && NR > line) {if (substr($0, 1,1)==">") exit; str=str$0}} END{print str}' f.fasta` i'm trying this and still getting empty string. maybe i'm missing something though.

Comment: `grep -Fw "$id" file` will do

Comment: thank you, this works. how would i find the line after the one with `$id`? i have `grep -A1 -Fw "$id" file` but that gives both the current line and the next one. I'd like to get just the second line of the output.

Comment: oh i figured it out. `grep -A1 -Fw "$id" file | sed -n 2p`. thank you so much!